# How to group by with mysql with all column divided in section for different groups in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, sorting

### Output needed :

#### Date 2017-2018

1):Sherlock
:Detective
2):Elon Musk
:Genius
3):Leo
:Hero

### Date 2015-2016

1):Robin
:Detective
2):Caprio
:Hero

### Date 2014-2015

1):Snow
:hero
2):Mr.x
:Unknown

```
Mysql Table:
+----+------------+----------+---------------------------+--------+
| id | date_from  | | name    |   desc
+----+------------+----------+---------------------------+--------+
| 1 | 2014-2015 | snow       |      hero      |
| 2 | 2014-2015 | Mr.x       |      unknown   |
| 3 | 2015-2016 | Robin      |      detective |
| 4 | 2015-2016 | Caprio     |      hero      |
+----+------------+----------+---------------------------+--------+
```

I can insert the data but how to sort it like the output ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date_from,GROUP_CONCAT(' ',name,' : ',`desc`) as name_desc 
from Table1 group by date_from
```

Output:

```
date_from   name_desc
2014-2015   snow : hero,Mr.x : unknown
2015-2016   Robin : detective,Caprio : hero
```

After Concat() above result

```
select Concat('Date ',date_from,' ',GROUP_CONCAT(' ',name,' : ',`desc`)) as name_desc 
from 
Table1 
group by date_from
```

Output

```
name_desc
Date 2014-2015 snow : hero, Mr.x : unknown
Date 2015-2016 Robin : detective, Caprio : hero
```

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7a6ca/32

Comment: So I cant style the 'name' and 'desc' separately?? I need to load the data in view and style them nicely .